# Slow Performance On Update SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, update, explain

I would like to ask your help. I have very slow update statements on this tables even if the table is only a basic table. I would like to know the reason for the slow update even if what I'm throwing is only a simple update.

update "NO_FORM_INV_DTL" set "VERSION" =  @P0 , "STATUS" =  @P1 , "UPDATED_DT" =  @P2  where "ID" =  @P3

There's a clustered index on ID.

Please advise what data you need. I'm running on SQL Server 2014. The update statement is really slow. I don't get it. Is it because of the implicit convert ? I pasted the explain plan below.

```
<ShowPlanXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan" Version="1.2" Build="12.0.4100.1"><BatchSequence><Batch><Statements><StmtSimple StatementText="(@P0 int,@P1 int,@P2 nvarchar(4000),@P3 datetime,@P4 nvarchar(4000),@P5 nvarchar(4000))update &quot;NO_FORM_INV_DTL&quot; set &quot;VERSION&quot; =  @P0 , &quot;STATUS&quot; =  @P1 , &quot;BOX_CD&quot; =  @P2 , &quot;UPDATED_DT&quot; =  @P3 , &quot;NO_FORM_TRANSFER_ID&quot; =  @P4  where &quot;ID&quot; =  @P5" StatementId="1" StatementCompId="1" StatementType="UPDATE" RetrievedFromCache="true" StatementSubTreeCost="15.4273" StatementEstRows="1" StatementOptmLevel="TRIVIAL" QueryHash="0xEF1E1FC6A7C07838" QueryPlanHash="0x49324E4A1CCCBF9" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="70"><StatementSetOptions QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" ARITHABORT="false" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" /><QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="32" CompileTime="2" CompileCPU="2" CompileMemory="352"><Warnings><PlanAffectingConvert ConvertIssue="Cardinality Estimate" Expression="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(32),[test-prd-tester-main].[dbo].[NO_FORM_INV_DTL].[ID],0)" /><PlanAffectingConvert ConvertIssue="Seek Plan" Expression="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(32),[test-prd-tester-main].[dbo].[NO_FORM_INV_DTL].[ID],0)=[@P5]" /></Warnings><MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" /><OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="314572" EstimatedPagesCached="314572" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="8" /><RelOp NodeId="0" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Update" LogicalOp="Update" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0.01" EstimateCPU="1e-006" AvgRowSize="9" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="15.4273" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList /><Update DMLRequestSort="0"><Object Database="[test-prd-tester-main]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[NO_FORM_INV_DTL]" Index="[PK_NO_FORM_INV_DTL_ID]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" /><SetPredicate><ScalarOperator ScalarString="[test-prd-tester-main].[dbo].[NO_FORM_INV_DTL].[VERSION] = RaiseIfNullUpdate([@P0]),[test-prd-tester-main].[dbo].[NO_FORM_INV_DTL].[STATUS] = RaiseIfNullUpdate([@P1]),[test-prd-tester-main].[dbo].[NO_FORM_INV_DTL].[BOX_CD] = [Expr1002],[test-prd-tester-main].[dbo].[NO_FORM_INV_DTL].[UPDATED_DT] = [@P3],[test-prd-tester-main].[dbo].[NO_FORM_INV_DTL].[NO_FORM_TRANSFER_ID] = [Expr1003]"><ScalarExpressionList><ScalarOperator><MultipleAssign><Assign><ColumnReference Database="[test-prd-tester-main]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[NO_FORM_INV_DTL]" Column="VERSION" /><ScalarOperator><Intrinsic FunctionName="RaiseIfNullUpdate"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="@P0" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Intrinsic></ScalarOperator></Assign><Assign><ColumnReference Database="[test-prd-tester-main]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[NO_FORM_INV_DTL]" Column="STATUS" /><ScalarOperator><Intrinsic FunctionName="RaiseIfNullUpdate"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="@P1" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Intrinsic></ScalarOperator></Assign><Assign><ColumnReference Database="[test-prd-tester-main]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[NO_FORM_INV_DTL]" Column="BOX_CD" /><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Assign><Assign><ColumnReference Database="[test-prd-tester-main]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[NO_FORM_INV_DTL]" Column="UPDATED_DT" /><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="@P3" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Assign><Assign><ColumnReference Database="[test-prd-tester-main]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[NO_FORM_INV_DTL]" Column="NO_FORM_TRANSFER_ID" /><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="Expr1003" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Assign></MultipleAssign></ScalarOperator></ScalarExpressionList></ScalarOperator></SetPredicate><RelOp NodeId="1" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="1e-007" AvgRowSize="68" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="15.4173" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[test-prd-tester-main]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[NO_FORM_INV_DTL]" Column="ID" /><ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" /><ColumnReference Column="Expr1003" /></OutputList><ComputeScalar><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" /><ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(10),[@P2],0)"><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1011"><ScalarOperator><Convert DataType="varchar" Length="10" Style="0" Implicit="1"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="@P2" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Convert></ScalarOperator></ColumnReference></Identifier></ScalarOperator></DefinedValue><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Column="Expr1003" /><ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(32),[@P4],0)"><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1012"><ScalarOperator><Convert DataType="varchar" Length="32" Style="0" Implicit="1"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="@P4" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Convert></ScalarOperator></ColumnReference></Identifier></ScalarOperator></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><RelOp NodeId="2" PhysicalOp="Index Scan" LogicalOp="Index Scan" EstimateRows="1" EstimateIO="13.6239" EstimateCPU="1.54126" AvgRowSize="43" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="15.1651" TableCardinality="1.401e+006" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row"><OutputList><ColumnReference Database="[test-prd-tester-main]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[NO_FORM_INV_DTL]" Column="ID" /></OutputList><IndexScan Ordered="1" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="0" ForceSeek="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0" Storage="RowStore"><DefinedValues><DefinedValue><ColumnReference Database="[test-prd-tester-main]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[NO_FORM_INV_DTL]" Column="ID" /></DefinedValue></DefinedValues><Object Database="[test-prd-tester-main]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[NO_FORM_INV_DTL]" Index="[IX_NO_FORM_INV_DTL]" IndexKind="NonClustered" Storage="RowStore" /><Predicate><ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(32),[test-prd-tester-main].[dbo].[NO_FORM_INV_DTL].[ID],0)=[@P5]"><Compare CompareOp="EQ"><ScalarOperator><Convert DataType="nvarchar" Length="64" Style="0" Implicit="1"><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Database="[test-prd-tester-main]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[NO_FORM_INV_DTL]" Column="ID" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Convert></ScalarOperator><ScalarOperator><Identifier><ColumnReference Column="@P5" /></Identifier></ScalarOperator></Compare></ScalarOperator></Predicate></IndexScan></RelOp></ComputeScalar></RelOp></Update></RelOp></QueryPlan></StmtSimple></Statements></Batch></BatchSequence></ShowPlanXML>
```

Just to add

```
(No column name)    execution_count total_logical_reads last_logical_reads  total_logical_writes    last_logical_writes total_worker_time   last_worker_time    Total_elapsed_time_Secs Last_elapsed_time_Secs  last_execution_time query_plan      



update "NO_FORM_INV_DTL" set "VERSION" =  @P0 , "STATUS" =  @P1 , "BOX_CD" =  @P2 , "UPDATED_DT" =  @P3 , "NO_FORM_TRANSFER_ID" =  @P4  where "ID" =  @P5   12106   225213777   18625   3493    0   12603012772 1061575 100328  11  2016-10-10 15:48:36.940
update "NO_FORM_INV_DTL" set "VERSION" =  @P0 , "STATUS" =  @P1 , "UPDATED_DT" =  @P2  where "ID" =  @P3    10938   203491896   18630   3423    1   11436325822 1058915 91826   11  2016-10-10 15:48:34.207
```

The size of the table is around 2 million records.
This should be a simple update. Don't know why it is slow.

Here is how the table looks like

[image]

Comment: It's doing an index scan because of the implicit conversion. If you view the warnings on the INSERT in the plan diagram, you'll see them.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not familiar. What is an implicit conversion and how do I avoid it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got some code, somewhere, converting your ID to an `NVARCHAR(32)` field. I don't know how or why this is happening, but that's causing it to ignore your index, resulting in a full scan instead of a seek.

[image: plan diagram]

Hovering over the warning on the `UPDATE`, we see this:

[image: UPDATE Warning]

There are two ways to fix this.

- The column is a `VARCHAR` and your code is generating `NVARCHAR`. This means you probably have an ORM generating the code, and there might be a switch to fix it.
- Otherwise, changing the column to `NVARCHAR` will work for this use case, but `NVARCHAR` (and `NCHAR`) are Unicode data types, which use twice as much disk space as `VARCHAR` and `CHAR` to store data.

Choose wisely.

Comment: So if I change it to nvarchar(32), the implicit conversion would be gone ? Thanks

Comment: I saw this link, I'm actually using JTDS to connect and SymmetricDS is the one actually throwing it. Is it possibly related to this issue ? http://www.digitalsanctuary.com/tech-blog/java/mssql-jtds-nvarchar-and-slow-indexes.html

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I added send string as Unicode false parameter and the plan changed drastically.